# Split text on page

Tags: java, android

How to split text between pages? Would like to know how to do HTML with the conclusion in the WebView or TextView, possibly even with images.

Comment: Need reader of books. Content includes text and images. It is necessary that the content is broken up into pages with a fixed height, so you can display a specific page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could split the text with css.

```
div {
-moz-column-count:2;
-webkit-column-count:2;
column-count:2;
}
```

IE not supported.